# How to generate a list of dates from multiple ranges, and match it with adjacent cell values

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Columns B to D are what I have in my raw sheet, and the next 2 columns is what I want to achieve with a click of a button. Would really appreciate some VBA coding help on this cos I have no idea where to start (VBA newbie here).

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a `VLOOKUP` formula, i.e. G2 is `=VLOOKUP(F2,$B:$D,3,TRUE)` and copy it down.  But, if you really want VBA, paste your current attempt into the question so that we can help you get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will help you problem

```
Dim dStart As Date
Dim dEnd As Date
Dim dDate As Date
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iColDate As Integer

iCol = 2
iColDate = 2

Do While Cells(iCol, 2).Value <> ""
    dStart = Format(Cells(iCol, 2).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    dEnd = Format(Cells(iCol, 3).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    For dDate = dStart To dEnd
        Cells(iColDate, 6).Value = dDate
        Cells(iColDate, 7).Value = Cells(iCol, 4).Value
        iColDate = iColDate + 1
    Next
    iCol = iCol + 1
Loop
```